# how to change repository location on gitolite?

Tags: linux, git, github, rhel, gitolite

I recently installed gitolite on my linux server.

This server is my git remote server with some bare repositories located on a separate path. lets say

```
/images/git_bare_repos
```

By default gitolite is installed on git user in home directory. I am able to clone gitolite-admin repository from the root user on the same machine. That is gitolite is working fine.

```
>>>ls /home/git
bin  gitolite  projects.list  repositories  root.pub
```

all the new repositories are created in repositories directory:

```
>>>ls /home/git/repositories/
gitolite-admin.git  testing.git
```

My question is:

I want gitolite to create new repositories on the same path where all my other bare repositories rest. Ie. in **`/images/git_bare_repos`**

I tried adding:

```
GL_REPO_BASE  => "/images/git_bare_repos",
```

in `.gitconfig.rc` file but with no luck.

Comment: That variable `GL_REPO_BASE`, needs to be added to the `gitolite.rc` (under `/etc/gitolite3/gitolite.rc` on my system, or as dotfile in your home directory). I guess your `.gitconfig.rc` was just a typo...

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach would be:

- export in your `.bashrc` `GL_REPO_BASE` to the right PATH;

Or:

- modify the `gitolite.rc` *before* the setup step

And then:

- re-install gitolite again, checking that it does pick up the environment variable PATH this time.

The [`src/lib/Gitolite/Rc.pm`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/29d5bb7a92ea0a22fa35077a5c4ca6af789ce117/src/lib/Gitolite/Rc.pm#L40-L41) does mention:

```
# these keys could be overridden by the rc file later
$rc{GL_REPO_BASE} = "$ENV{HOME}/repositories";
```

Comment: You wrote that it is necessary to re-install gitolite. Does that apply to the first point and the second point, or just the second point? It is not clear from your answer, as you used a flat itemized list.

Comment: @JonathanKomar It is the second step after having done one of the first two points. I have edited the answer.